# How do I use the @objc extension in the framework?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, error-handling, frameworks

I put the framework I created into a project I'm currently working on. Inside the framework there is a function called moveToCenter. I am getting an error using moveToCenter in my project. How to fix it?

```swift
@objc
extension UIView {
    public func moveToCenter() {
        ...
        ...
    }
}
```

But when I delete @objc it works fine. Is there any way to solve it without deleting @objc?

I added my own framework to Embed Frameworks, Frameworks, Libraries, and Embeded Content.

// Error Message

```
libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MyProjectName[moveToCenter]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ff6a0022f20'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
CoreSimulator 757.5 - Device: iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (5th generation) (7AD9C806-BB59-4398-B8E5-C920514FC064) - Runtime: iOS 14.5 (18E182) - DeviceType: iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (5th generation)
```

my File structure
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8imT6.png

Comment: Could you fix the full error message? To assert that the object calling `moveToCenter` is indeed a `UIView` object?

Comment: @Larme Are you asking me to show the full error message?

Comment: `'-[MyProjectName[enter image description here][1] moveToCenter]` That part essentially, it's not the correct one because of `enter image description here`

Comment: Thank you. I entered something else in the bro but I entered it incorrectly haha I corrected it right away!

Comment: Could you put the real error message? It's important to check that the object calling that method is really an UIView.

Comment: The actual code for that part is '[Maker.ImageEditTextLabelView moveToCenter]'

Comment: Is `ImageEditTextLabelView` a subclass of `UIView`? Did you do the #import yourFramework? Does the autocompletion when you call that method helps you write the method?

Comment: First of all, the subview is correct. I also imported.
It was auto-completed and used!

Comment: Maybe you need add `-ObjC` into linking flags?

Comment: I'll add ObjC and test it.

Comment: Because ObjC was added
An error occurs.  [ 397 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64]

Comment: Look's like you have some sources used in both targets